# How to get rid of Dark Souls 2's "There is no new information" modal prompt?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There's "no new information" about literally an infinite amount of things at all times. There doesn't seem to be anything for this on [Nexus Mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls2/?). Am I missing something, or is this the most useless prompt ever made? And most importantly, **how do I get rid of it?**

Comment: Are you talking about the pop-up that shows up when you start the game? If so, you aren't missing anything, it's just where patch notes or announcements would be if any had been applied since you last logged in. I agree that it's odd they didn't just implement it such that the box only shows up when there _are_ patch notes or announcements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @pushasha mentioned in the comments; this prompt is just for new release notes.

Since the game is (likely) no longer going to be updated after the release of DkS3, this prompt is going to remain as "No new information" until Skynet destroys us all.

The only point this prompt serves is if (for whatever reason) you lose all the information, have to re-install the game, it will have to update again; and this prompt (should) show you all the changes made since the first release.

As for getting rid of it; there is no documented, or managed way (as of yet). However, since you implied you were on a PC (i.e. the suggestion of mods) I would dare say changing a "true/false" prompt somewhere in the code, or maybe writing a macro to "auto-accept" the prompt would be your best bet for managing this - deleting files or denying access to them may cause the program to crash.

Comment: Sorry! I have edited my answer. Unfortunately since this prompt is little more than a minor annoyance, not many people pay heed to it. So you'll have to either deal with it, or find a way to remove it yourself.