# Is there a way to rid of "Notifications and announcements" message?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-3

Every time I quit to the main menu to load another character there is "Notifications and announcements" message appears. Since I do it a lot this is very annoying.
Is there a way to never see it again? Or a way to mark it as read and thereby see each announcement only once.

Comment: Are you on console or PC? Just to clarify

Comment: @Ben i am on PC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of Dark Souls 2's "There is no new information" modal prompt?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271133/how-to-get-rid-of-dark-souls-2s-there-is-no-new-information-modal-prompt)

Comment: VTLO: A solution for DS2 will not necessarily work for DS3.

Comment: @Schism generally, true. But this situation is exactly the same as in Dark souls 2. There is no "off button" for this prompt, and due to its simple functionality, the need for removing this is minimal, so the likelihood of this being a thing is unlikely.